# Conversion from string " " to type 'Decimal' is not valid. - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, grid

trying to convert it to decimal gives error 
it is row cell of gridview

```
e.Row.Cells(i).Text = If(CType(e.Row.Cells(total).Text, Decimal) = 0, "-", (CType(e.Row.Cells(total).Text, Decimal) * 100 / CType(e.Row.Cells(total).Text, Decimal)).ToString("0.00") + "%")
```

Comment: Please Help !! TXXX

Comment: try TryCast instead of CType

Comment: It gives --Error 20 'TryCast' operand must be reference type, but 'Decimal' is a value type.

Comment: @N1gthm4r3 : `TryCast` _definitely_ wouldn't have fixed anything. It is used for casting `Object`s into their actual type, _not_ for data type conversion.

Comment: You should put this in a function. You are converting string to decimal 3 times, you should do it only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim temp As Decimal
temp=0
IF Decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells(total).Text, temp) THEN
e.Row.Cells(i).Text = If(temp = 0, "-", (temp * 100 / temp).ToString("0.00") + "%")
ELSE e.Row.Cells(i).Text = "-"
```

Comment: @StavanShah instead of where he does `out Decimal` switch it to `temp` I think he just got a bit mixed up :)

Comment: This code is missing `End If` and will not compile.